# Display array items with custom space using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, function

I am trying to display a string[], which is like

**JS Code**

```
var result = ["Fish","Mutton","Shrimp","Chicken"];
$scope.res = result;
```

I get all the array values in $scope.res and displayed in HTML using ng-bind,

**HTML code**

```
<span ng-bind="res"></span>
```

*Result: Fish,Mutton,Shrimp,Chicken*

*Needed Result: Fish, Mutton, Shrimp, Chicken*

I need to add space between every array value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `join` method.

> The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like
>   object) into a string.

JS

```
var result = ["Fish","Mutton","Shrimp","Chicken"];
$scope.res = result.join(', ');
```

HTML

```
<span ng-bind="res"></span>
```

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var result = ["Fish","Mutton","Shrimp","Chicken"];
    $scope.res = result.join(', ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <span ng-bind="res"></span>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```